# Accessing the error model in Ember ErrorRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to write a handler for all failed routes in my Ember application.

The documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates) seems to suggest that I can make a ErrorRoute on my App object which will automatically be transitioned to when routing on another route failed. I want to use this to redirect the user to a login page if the reason for the routing failure is due to an authentication problem (such as token timeout).

The problem I have is that inside the ErrorRoute I don't seem to have any way to access the error returned by the route that failed. I want to check for sure that it was an authentication error before redirecting them to the login screen and I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is what I wrote for testing:

```
App.ErrorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        console.log("MODEL A", this.modelFor('error'));

        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("MODEL B", this.modelFor('error'));
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
});
```

When the route is activated, the console logs `MODEL A undefined` as it tries to access the model for the App.ErrorController which isn't set yet for some reason. After a second the `MODEL B` console log fires and the error model has been set up.

If I can't access the error in the Route's `activate` method then where can I access it? Presumably I'm not supposed to wrap my logic in a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manage the error in any route of your current active hierarchy.

Normally, you setup your error handler at the application route to perform your app error logic.

```
App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  afterModel: function() {

    return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){

      throw new AuthenticatedError('error message');

    });
  }

});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  actions: {

    error: function(error) {

      if ( error instanceof AuthenticatedError ) {
        this.transitionTo('login');
      } else {
        // if return true, the event will bubble and transition to error 
        return true;
      }

    }

  }

});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cisur/1/edit

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks ppcano.

I wonder why the official guide suggested using the ErrorRoute for redirecting to a login screen. This makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The error model is passed to the error route's `renderTemplate(controller, model)` method.

If you don't care about landing on a `*.error` route substate, if you're going to redirect anyway, @ppcano's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534573/62269) is sufficient. But sometimes you want to encapsulate all error handling in a dedicated error route object. `renderTemplate` then is your place to handle things.

I agree though, it would be nice if its hooks had the correct `modelFor(...)` available.